.NET Core SDK/runtime 2.2 and 3.0 are now End of Life(EOL) and have been removed from all hosted agents
Updated my application to .NET 8. Getting an error in Azure pipeline.
YAML looks like this
steps:
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Install .NET Core runtime'
    inputs:
      packageType: "runtime"
      version: "8.0.6"
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: "Using DotNet@2"
    inputs:
      packageType: "sdk"
      version: "8.0.302"
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: "Install dotnet format"
    inputs:
      command: "custom"
      custom: "tool"
      arguments: "update -g dotnet-format"
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: "Lint dotnet"
    inputs:
      command: "custom"
      custom: "format"
      arguments: "--check --verbosity diagnostic"
      workingDirectory: backend

Each task is successful but getting an error shown below:

.NET Core SDK/runtime 2.2 and 3.0 are now End of Life(EOL) and have been removed from all hosted agents.....
/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/dotnet format --check --verbosity diagnostic
Unhandled exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The file '--check' does not appear to be a valid project or solution file.

What's causing the issue? Am i missing something?

.NET Core SDK/runtime 2.2 and 3.0 are now End of Life... is just a warning that is displayed when using the DotNetCoreCLI@2 task in the Microsoft-Hosted agents, so nothing to worry about.

According to GitHub issue #30102, --check has been replaced by --verify-no-changes.
To verify that all code is correctly formatted, run:
dotnet format --verify-no-changes

This should fix your task:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "Lint dotnet"
  inputs:
    command: "custom"
    custom: "format"
    arguments: "--verify-no-changes --verbosity diagnostic"
    workingDirectory: backend

For more details and examples see the dotnet format command documentation.

Thank you. This solved the issue. However, started getting another error which is different than this one. Posting separate question for it.
